# \DTLfetch not working with Variable

Tags: pdftex, datatool, for-loop

I have csv database loaded in `data` variable.
I am trying to fetch value from particular column given an another column name and its value.
I am using following code

```
\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 30}
{
 \DTLfetch{data}{Number}{\value{i}}{Day}
}
```

Above code works well when there is hard coded numerical value like `1,2,3,...` but somehow it is not able to catch the value of argument `\value{i}`. What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\value` gives the value of the counter as an internal integer.
This is fine if you compare it with another integer as in `{\value{i} < 30}`,
but for `\DTLfetch` you need the representation of the number in arabic numerals,
not just some internal integer.
So you can use

```
\forloop{i}{1}{\value{i} < 30}
{
 \DTLfetch{data}{Number}{\arabic{i}}{Day}
}
```